# Is there a way in Postgres to convert an excel file store in a database as bytea to a table of columns with the real data

Tags: pandas, postgresql, dataframe, csv, bytea

I have loaded data from an excel spreadsheet that was located on Gitlab and stored it as a bytea column in a master table. Now I need to create a table which will contain the actual columns present in the spreadsheet and convert the bytea to the actual data and insert into this table. How can this be done? Any ideas will be appreciated.
P.S I could have saved the excel spreadsheet to .csv and loaded to DB using the COPY command. But I do not want to do any conversions on the raw data but to store in in binary format till I begin my transformations

Comment: An Excel file as `bytea` in the database is completely useless. The only way I can think of is to export as CSV.

Comment: I did see a post on stack overflow which talks about using pandas in plpython3u and converting the bytea to a dataframe. Not sure if that would work.

Comment: Perhaps... but wouldn't using Excel be much simpler?

Comment: Yes that is perhaps the best option and I agree. But what I am trying to achieve is a Data Vault structure where I am using Postgres http client to retrieve the data from the Excel Spreadsheet which is stored in Gitlab using the api and that is being returned as base64 encoded. So the only option I have is to decode it to binary format and store it in my database.

Comment: There are modules in Perl, and I'm sure python as well, that let you parse Excel files.  So the role of PostgreSQL is just to vomit forth the file to one of those modules.  While you could try to parse it in pl/pgsql or even SQL, that would really be a mistake.